# What is the date command line corresponding to var="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"

Tags: command-line, date

If I run the following command line on Ubuntu:

```
var="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"
echo var
```

I can get the desired output. But If I just run

```
date +%x %r %Z
```

I will be given errors:

> date: extra operand ‘%r’
>
> Try 'date --help' for more information.

So what is the date command corresponding to `var="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"`? Thanks.

Comment: The date command is `date +"%x %r %Z"` with the quotes on it so that it knows that all the % are part of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not copy exactly the same command. You wrote `date +"%x %r %Z"` inside parentheses. This just work well outside. Otherwise, `date` has three arguments (`+%x`, `%r` and `%Z`), rather than one (`+%x %r %Z`).

From `man bash` :

> When  using  the  $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
>   Command substitutions may be nested.

Parentheses are matched before evaluating the content, so the command is not split as `$(date +%x`, `%r`, `%Z)` .

Note :
You forgot the `$` of `echo $var`.

Comment: Why does bash not interpret the assignment to be "$(date +" followed by %x %r %Z and then by ")"? We know var="aaa"bbb"ccc" ls is ok.

Comment: @user5280911 I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the date command corresponding to var="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"?

Well as already stated in another answer you missed to quote the options right, it should be at least:

```
date +"%x %r %Z"
```

This is needed because you are using white-spaces to keep the different information apart, the [man page for date](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/date.1.html) suggests using `-`, or `_`, with this you could omit the quoting all together in normal terminal, or you escape the white-spaces.

---

> ## Examples:
>
> - using '-' as divider
>
>   ```
>   date +%x-%r%Z
>   ```
>
>   gives the following output:
>
>   ```
>   21.09.2018-11:30:15 CEST
>   ```
> - using '_' as divider
>
>   ```
>   date +%x_%r%Z
>   ```
>
>   gives the following output:
>
>   ```
>   21.09.2018_11:30:15 CEST
>   ```
> - using escaped white-spaces as divider
>
>   ```
>   date +%x\ %r%Z
>   ```
>
>   gives the following output:
>
>   ```
>   21.09.2018 11:30:15 CEST
>   ```
> - using no dividers at all
>
>   ```
>   date +%x%r%Z
>   ```
>
>   gives the following output:
>
>   ```
>   21.09.201811:30:15 CEST
>   ```

---

Remainder for a special use case. When you try to incorporate date into a `crontab` command, you need to escape the `%` sign too. So as undivided information the command would look like this (Before mentioned rules apply for escaping still):

```
date +\%x\%r\%Z
```